# send html mail using codeigniter

Tags: html, email, codeigniter

Error in  mail content using SMTP in codeigniter 
Actually, my mail is sent with `HTML` tags and it is showing the `HTML` tags which is not correct.

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'user@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE

    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $email_body ="<div>hello world</div>";
    $this->email->from('user@gmail.com', 'ddd');

    $list = array('user@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to($list);
    $this->email->subject('Testing Email');
    $this->email->message($email_body);

    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

If am sending mail without using SMTP it works fine. What is my mistake?

Comment: I don't think `ssl://` is part of a host name.  Maybe there's another setting to turn on SSL?

Comment: codeigniter full html email configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38740292/4376484

Answer (score 78):

You can try this line of code which will set the mail type to be for `HTML`:

```
 $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

Comment: no accepted answers yet?

Answer (score 25):

As of [CodeIgniter 3.x](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#id2). There are many features added. This example is almost same with earlier versions, but you can do much more.

Follow the link for documentation.

```
// load email library
$this->load->library('email');

// prepare email
$this->email
    ->from('info@example.com', 'Example Inc.')
    ->to('to@example.com')
    ->subject('Hello from Example Inc.')
    ->message('Hello, We are <strong>Example Inc.</strong>')
    ->set_mailtype('html');

// send email
$this->email->send();
```

If you have template design. You can also include template in `message` method like this ...

```
->message($this->load->view('email_template', $data, true))
```

Here, the first parameter is `email_template.php` in your views directory, second parameter the data to be sent to email template, you can set it `''` or `array()` or `[]` if not passing any dynamic data and last parameter `true` make sure, you grab the template data instead output.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I already tried this way. Email sent successfully. but the problem is images inside my html body is not visible. all the text and styles applied. but no images. what is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the mail type to `HTML` works for me:

```
$email_setting  = array('mailtype'=>'html');
$this->email->initialize($email_setting);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to manually set the content type header doing this:

```
$this->email->set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

That solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

To send HTML email you first have to compose your message in a variable and then pass that variable to codeigniter's "$this->email->message()" method, like below,

```
 $this->load->library('email');

 $message = "
     <html>
       <head>
         <title>your title</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         <p>Hello Sir,</p>
         <p>Your message</p>
       </body>
     </html>";

   $this->email->from('email id', 'name');
   $this->email->to('email id');

   $this->email->subject('email subject');
   $this->email->message($message);

   if ($this->email->send()) {
     print "success";
   } else {
     print "Could not send email, please try again later";
   }
```

hope it will help.

enjoy!!

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try with this code, B'z I can able to send HTML email with this code.

```
$configemail = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //mail.webconsort.com
        'smtp_port' => 465, //5074
        'smtp_user' => 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com', //tororide@webconsort.com
        'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXXXXX', //'T0r0r1d3'
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->library('email', $configemail);

    $CI->email->initialize($configemail);
    $CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $CI->email->from($from, $fromName);
    $CI->email->to($to); 

    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($body);
    if ($attachments != null && !empty($attachments)){
        foreach($attachments as $a){
            $CI->email->attach($a);
        }
    }

    try{
        $CI->email->send();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        //var_dump($e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Gmail prevent access of your account. You need some changes on your gmail :-

**Step : 1**

> Some apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology, which makes
>   your account more vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps,
>   which we recommend, or turn on access if you want to use them despite
>   the risks.

[Turn on less secure app](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

**Step : 2**

> Enable IMAP Status
>     Enable POP Status

[Enable IMAP and POP Status](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop)

Answer (score 1):

add this code lines:

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->set_crlf("\r\n");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that Codeigniter's Global XSS Filtering was encoding some html tags like `<html>` so the email clients could no longer recognize them.

To get around this, check out my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11525519/726312).

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this.. it works great for me.

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from($fromemail);

$this->email->to($toemail);

$this->email->subject('Subject');

$this->email->message($html);

$success=$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
';

$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mail.example.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'noreply@example.com',
'smtp_pass' => 'example@123',
'mailtype'  => 'html',
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('noreply@example.com', 'example');
$this->email->to('example@example.in');
$this->email->subject('Enquiry');
$this->email->message($message);
```

Comment: This answer may be correct, but you should elaborate on how your example code crucially differs from the one in the question. (I'd guess the important difference is the set_mailtype("html"); line in your code, which is missing from the code in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

PHP code/CodeIgniter :

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'; //smtp host name
$config['smtp_port'] = '465'; //smtp port number
$config['smtp_user'] = $from_email;
$config['smtp_pass'] = "password_addhere"; //$from_email password
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
// $config['charset'] = "iso-8859-1";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
// $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
// $this->email->initialize($config);
$this->load->library("email", $config);
//send mail
$this->email->from($from_email, 'ABC OWNER');
$this->email->to($to_email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($this->load->view('mails/contact',$data, true));
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");

return $this->email->send();
```

VIEW FILE in HTML :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Contact Form</title> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
            <h1>New user contacted for information</h1> 
            <table cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px  #000; width: 100%;"> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Customer Name:</th><td><?php echo $name; ?><br/></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;"> 
                    <th>Email:</th><td><?php echo $email; ?><br/></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Phone:</th><td><?php echo $phone; ?><br></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Message:</th><td><?php echo $message; ?><br></td> 
            </tr> 
            </table> 
        </body> 
        </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

U will try it!! it's working for mine after showing many errors it's 100% working.

```
        $subject = 'New message.';
        $config = Array(        
            'protocol' => 'sendmail',
            'smtp_host' => 'Your smtp host',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'webmail',
            'smtp_pass' => 'webmail pass',
            'smtp_timeout' => '4',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'utf-8',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
        $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');

        $this->email->from('from mail address', 'Company name ');
        $data = array(
             'message'=> $this->input->post('message')
                 );
        $this->email->to($toEmail);  
        $this->email->subject($subject); 

        $body = $this->load->view('email/sendmail.php',$data,TRUE);
        $this->email->message($body);   
        $this->email->send();
```