# How to send email from localhost using CodeIgniter with Gmail

Tags: php, smtp, localhost, codeigniter-3

Hello everyone, I'm currently working on a CodeIgniter application in which user will be able to create their own accounts,etc.

I'm trying to create a function to recover password in case is lost or forgotten. 

Here is my code:

```
    public function admin_recover(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[7]|valid_email');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //Load View Into Template

        $this->template->load('admin', 'login', 'users/recover');

    } else {
        //Get Post Data
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $user_email = $this->User_model->get_list();

        if($user_email){
            $user_email_data = array(
                'email' => true
            );
        ///////// Sending email
        // Configure email library

        $config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
        $config['charset']='utf-8';
        $config['newline']="\r\n";
        $config['priority']=1;
        $config['protocol']='smtp';
        $config['smtp_host']='ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port']='25';
        $config['smtp_timeout']='30';
        $config['smtp_user']='kuaf1998@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass']='mypassword';
        $config['newline']="\r\n";


        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('no-reply@socialgeek.com', 'Social Geek');
        $this->email->to('kebin1421@hotmail.com');       
        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
        $this->email->send();


        if($this->email->send()) 
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Email sent successfully."); 
        else 
        $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Error in sending Email.");

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        //////////////      
        }   
    }
}
```

I'm using the gmail smtp service to send emails from my localhost but I'm still unable to make it happen. Any idea how can I fix this?

I already did some changes on(I'm using xampp) the ini file which is found on my xampp>php>php.ini

When I go to the view, I get this error:

[image]

Thanks for helping.

Comment: use `['smtp_port']='25';` as `465`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send html mail using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095528/send-html-mail-using-codeigniter)

Comment: I already did and I still get the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these configuration settings below and let me know if it works for you.

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'user@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'yourpassword',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```

Comment: Are you sure mail() function is not disabled in your server configuration?

Comment: What do you mean?. For what I know all I had to do was to "un-comment" the extension on the ini file right? "extension=php_smtp.dll"