# Codeigniter $_GET validation, XSS Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, xss

I have an issue with XSS vulnerability in my site that is built on CodeIgniter.

I do have `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` and as you can see below, I also set the `,TRUE` parameter to force it to filter XSS.

I type in my input `"<h1>test"` and `var_dump($parameters['query']);` outputs:

```
string(10) ""
data""
```

The problem with the above output is the break line, any reason why is that happening?

Array:

```
   $parameters = array(
        'query'     => $this->input->get('search_query', TRUE),
        'page'      => !empty($page) ? $page : 1,
        'sort'      => !empty($sort) ? $sort : 'relevance',
        'filter'    => $this->input->get('search_filter', TRUE),
        'action'    => $action,
        'view'      => $action.'sPage'
    );
```

### UPDATE:

This is what I see in view source: `"<h1>data"`

Comment: `global_xss_filtering` filters scripts, meaning it will complain if you have <elements>. I recommend turning xss filtering off globally, and on only for the places that need it. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899777/codeigniter-global-xss-filtering

Comment: can you please "view source" of your output page and paste the actual source of the view, not what is displayed on screen? Thanks

Comment: I updated my question with the view source result. @Zenbait, I will do that... tnx