# Codeigniter 2.1, MySQL - insert image source into DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codeigniter global_xss_filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899777/codeigniter-global-xss-filtering)

I have small problem with inserting image source (HTML tag) into DB. For example in **textarea** there is part which goes like this:

```
<img src"http://10.0.0.101/okc/public/img/vesti/event Za Dz Cacak.jpg"  />
```

When I try to load text of the article instead of format from above I get this:

```
<img cacak.jpg"="" dz="" za="" event="" vesti="" img="" public="" okc="" 10.0.0.101="" src"http:="">
```

This part of the code inserts article text in DB:

```
...

    'opis'=>mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($this->input->post('text'))),
...
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Just curious... is it a valid image name? (with blank spaces)

Comment: In my case global_xss_filtering is set to false.

Comment: @manix Name of the image is valid.

Comment: 'opis'=>$this->db->escape($this->input->post('text', TRUE)), you should be sanitizing this way.

Comment: I manage to find it problem. **html_entity_decode** is stripping slashes (//). How can I avoid this?

Comment: DO NOT use htmlentities() or any mysql_() functions, Codeigniter has built in ways to do both of those which would be more thorough. See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/security.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to do what you are trying to do:

```
'opis'=>$this->db->escape($this->input->post('text', TRUE)),
```

See this for more info on how to securely code:

- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/security.html