# Cannot save in database inline styles of texarea

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter-2

I have a textarea in which we can write html code. When the user saves it, a jQuery post is sent.

The server saves the textarea in MySQL.

However, all the styles are stripped.

```
<table style="color:red">...</table>
```

Becomes

```
<table >...</table>
```

Classes are kept, just styles are removed.

I looked into the http data (via Firebug) : jQuery sends the correct data. But when I echo the data on the server it is already stripped...

EDIT : I tried

- Client side : escape() and encodeURIComponent(). The data is correctly sent (even without these functions)
- Server side : As soon as I do a echo $_POST["value"], the inline styles are already gone (replaced by a space). Yet I tried htmlentities, and all the html encode/decode functions. I even did echo $_POST in the __construct method before the parent gets construct.

Comment: What server side language/frameworks are you using?

Comment: Using PHP/CodeIgniter 2 on the server. When I echo $_POST["data"], the styles are gone.

Comment: try escaping your data string

Comment: @muneebShabbir Doesn't change anything

Comment: maybe it have something to do with $config['global_xss_filtering']

Comment: @steven Thank you ! I turned it off and it works ! Please make your comment into an answer so I can valid it. (Why would CI even clean the native php array !?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all post data is filtered when

```
 $config['global_xss_filtering'] = true;
```

please read this: [Codeigniter global_xss_filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899777/codeigniter-global-xss-filtering)

and this: [Codeigniter - Disable XSS filtering on a post basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788476/codeigniter-disable-xss-filtering-on-a-post-basis)

and this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html