# my post is being cleared whenever there is <iframe> in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, iframe

hi here is my problem I have a form

```
<div class="default-form" id="website_form" data-method="website">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-transparent"> <strong>Website Information</strong> </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="validate well" id="default_form" onsubmit="return false;" data-toastr-position="top-right" data-success="Sent! Thank you!" novalidate="novalidate">
            <fieldset> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <label>Title *</label> <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="{$set_data.DEF_TITLE}" name="d[DEF_TITLE]" id="DEF_TITLE"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <button id="submit_form" data-fid="default_form" class="btn btn-3d btn-primary btn-xlg btn-block margin-top-30" type="submit">
                            UPDATE
                        </button> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the parameteres being sent is this

```
d[DEF_TITLE]    sample message <iframe></iframe>
```

and the source is this

```
DEF_TITLE%5D=sample+message+%3Ciframe%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E
```

after I submit my form via ajax and now my code for my serverside (where the post will be directed) is this

```
function procedure()
    {
            $fs = $this->input->post('d');
            print_r('bbb');
            print_r($fs);
            exit;
    }
```

I recieve empyt in my post. But if I remove the `<iframe>` or `<iframe></iframe>` in the text that I will input in the form, the post will now have a value. How is this possible? I used php codeigniter only. Please help me for I really tried all that I can think of... Thanks...

---

Additional Info for my ajax used:

```
var posts = $('#default_form').serialize();
    $.post(path + "/procedure/", posts, function(result) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(result);
});
```

---

Additional Info seems like html tag  makes the post disappeared only. I tried `"test <b>",  "test <html>",  "test <div>",  "test <strong>",  "test <ul>",  "test <li>",  "test <table>"` and they all works well in post

Comment: the post function may have escaped your iframe for security reasons

Comment: along with the paramamters and source I notice a 403 Forbidden appears when <iframe> is included in the value...

Comment: how can that be possible in codeigniter? I removed the iframe in the security.php @madalinivascu

Comment: What happens when you use `$fs=$_POST['d']`? Sounds like you have `global_xss_filtering` turned on in your config. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899777/codeigniter-global-xss-filtering

Comment: @charlietfl my global_xss_filtering in config.php is in FALSE, that code gives me this error,  


<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: d</p>

Comment: Try `print_r($this->input->post())` ... not even sure what `d` is

Comment: @charlietfl tried that and here is the result : Array
(
)

Comment: use get, from what i can tell you are doing a get request

Comment: how is data being sent? You have `onsubmit="return false;"` so must be using ajax but no ajax code shown. Where is `and the source is this` actually being inspected?

Comment: @madalinivascu I tried the get with these codes print_r($this->input->get('d')); no result displayed, while print_r($this->input->get()); displayed Array ( )

Comment: @charlietfl yes I use ajax but I'm not sure because working well if there is no <iframe>.. but updated my info at the top for my ajax, I am using firefox and I look at the console.

Comment: yes I type this in the input field: test <iframe>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: change the name of the input

```
 <label>Title *</label> <input type="text" class="form-control
 required" value="{$set_data.DEF_TITLE}" name="def_title"
 id="DEF_TITLE"> 

 $fs = $this->input->post('def_title');
```

Comment: Hi, tried that with print_r and empty was displayed. And the serialized generated is ctn=2bc6e877f3d9697e6ef04ee210a20158&def_title=test+%3Ciframe%3E&is_ajax=true

Comment: I just noticed that even <b> <div> it does not display any post. I think any html tags make the post disappear..

Comment: var_dump($_POST['def_title'])

Comment: I tried that and recieved this error: 
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: def_title</p> NULL

Comment: make sure your input is named def_title

Comment: yes I'm very sure I still recieve same PHP error, also i just notice and seems like it is not all html talgs, only iframe makes the posts disappeared.

Comment: why do you even need a iframe in a text input ?

Comment: actually it should be in textarea but since input is just the same process with textarea when it comes to passing of value I just used input here. I need to include youtube embedded with other content details.